# How to enable NSZombie while running XCTest?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xctest

I have extensive XCTest unit test, sometimes when i run it, I encouter EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Is there any way to enable NSZombie while running the test code ?

i tried [Is it possible to run XCTest based tests under Instruments in Xcode 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031263/is-it-possible-to-run-xctest-based-tests-under-instruments-in-xcode-5) but it doesn't seem to work when i run the test bundle

Answer (score 0):

You can set Environment Variable's `NSZombieEnabled` on YES for your test target.

[Here](http://nshipster.com/launch-arguments-and-environment-variables/) you have some more details.